# Why is `const T&` not sure to be const?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, function-templates, const-reference

```
template<typename T>
void f(T a, const T& b)
{
    ++a; // ok
    ++b; // also ok!
}

template<typename T>
void g(T n)
{
    f<T>(n, n);
}

int main()
{
    int n{};
    g<int&>(n);
}
```

Please note: `b` is of `const T&` and `++b` is ok!

**Why is `const T&` not sure to be const?**

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Welcome to const and [reference collapsing](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6).  When you have `const T&`, the reference gets applied to `T`, and so does the `const`.  You call `g` like

```
g<int&>(n);
```

so you have specified that `T` is a `int&`.  When we apply a reference to an lvalue reference, the two references collapse to a single one, so `int& &` becomes just `int&`.  Then we get to the rule from [[dcl.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ref#1), which states that if you apply `const` to a reference it is discarded, so `int& const` just becomes `int&` (note that you can't actually declare `int& const`, it has to come from a typedef or template).  That means for

```
g<int&>(n);
```

you are actually calling

```
void f(int& a, int& b)
```

and you are not actually modifying a constant.

---

Had you called `g` as

```
g<int>(n);
// or just
g(n);
```

then `T` would be `int`, and `f` would have been stamped out as

```
void f(int a, const int& b)
```

Since `T` isn't a reference anymore, the `const` and the `&` get applied to it, and you would have received a compiler error for trying to modify a constant variable.

Comment: This is why the type traits like [`std::add_lvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) exist, to ensure that references are added in a predictable way to prevent just this sort of pain.

Comment: One way to make it easier to understand is to write `T const&` instead of `const T&` (which is the same), and then replace `T` with `int&`.

Comment: I would reorder some of the first part of this answer, since in the type `const T&`, first the `const` applies to `T`, and then the lvalue-reference applies to the result of that.  (If the rule were the opposite, the "const applied to a reference type is ignored" rule would always kick in, and `const T&` would always mean the same as `T&`.)

Comment: @aschepler The rules stop `T& const`, not `const T&`/`T const &`

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm just suggesting discussing the effect of `const` before the effect of lvalue-reference, since `using U = const T&;` means the same as `using tmp1 = const T; using U = tmp1&;` but not the same as `using tmp2 = T&; using U = const tmp2;`

Comment: I have to wonder if this is a variation on the issue addressed in this article: http://www.drdobbs.com/conversationsa-midsummer-nights-madness/184403835 .  Granted, the article addresses `typedefs` while this is template types, but the same underlying issue exists.  `Tptr` in the article and `T` here are "atomic" types in that while they do contain an indirection/ reference, you can't inject a `const` between the underlying type and the indirection/reference.

Comment: @dgnuff yes, it is the same.  This happens when the type is "wrapped" in a single name.

Comment: @NathanOliver As I read this answer, you have stated that the reference collapsing rule "happens" before the const collapsing rule, which I think is wrong. If you have `int & const &`, then you need to apply the const rule first to get `int & &`, then the reference rule to get `int&`. I agree that the first bit needs rewording. Maybe an English "translation" is also in order: "The argument to `g<T>` is a constant reference to `T`. The argument to `g<int&>` is a constant reference to a reference to `int`. A constant reference to a reference is just a reference. This is formalized in C++ by ..."

Answer (score -3):

I know that there is already an accepted answer which is correct but just to add to it a little bit, even outside the realm of templates and just in function declarations in general...

```
( const T& )
```

is not the same as

```
( const T )
```

In your example which matches the first, you have a const reference. If you truly want a const value that is not modifiable remove the reference as in the second example.

Comment: when `T` is `int&`, `const T&` and `const T` both give `int&`.

Comment: I think there was a misconception on what I was trying to say; I'm using T here not as a `template` parameter. T was just meant to be used as any data type: `int`, `float`, `double` etc.. so `T` in my example above should never be `int&`. I did specifically state outside the realm of templates.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds as if you are explaining that you can see this without templates, which is no problem.  But then your final sentence claims to offer a solution to OP's problem, and that problem definitely involves templates.  It's fine to offer a solution to a template question which is broader than just templates.  But a solution to a template question that isn't accurate for templates, seems not to answer the question.

Comment: This can also be an issue with no templates involved: `using T = int&; void f(const T&);` declares `void f(int&);`.

Comment: @aschepler true, but I wasn't referring to `using` clauses; just basic function declarations in general.